# Grid view locking button by user id

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview, foreach

I have a gridview in my project where like twitter you can see other peoples post but i want to allow users to change there posts and because of that near every post i putted an edit button.  Now my problem is i cant lock the button if the user didnt post that tweet. can you show me how i can check if the users id (a given variable) matches the tweet user id (hidden field) i thought on using the for each loop but i cant succeed using it.

```
 <asp:GridView ID="GridView1" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="False" 
        ShowHeader="False" onrowcommand="GridView1_RowCommand" 
        onrowediting="GridView1_RowEditing" OnRowCancelingEdit="GridView1_Cancel" 
        onrowupdating="GridView1_RowUpdating" 
        onrowdeleting="GridView1_RowDeleting"  >
    <Columns>
    <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="UserName">
    <ItemTemplate>
    <asp:Label ID="lbl_Username" runat="server" Text='<%#Eval("UserName") %>'></asp:Label>
    </ItemTemplate>
    </asp:TemplateField>
    <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Tweet">
    <ItemTemplate>
    <asp:Label ID="lbl_Tweet" runat="server" Text='<%#Eval("TweetText") %>'></asp:Label>
    </ItemTemplate>
    <EditItemTemplate>
    <asp:TextBox ID="Tbx_Tweet" runat="server" Text='<%#Eval("TweetText") %>' ></asp:TextBox>
    </EditItemTemplate>
    </asp:TemplateField>
    <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Picture">
    <ItemTemplate>
    <asp:Image ID="Pic" runat="server"  ImageUrl='<%#"~/UploadedImages/"+Eval("PicName") %>' />
    </ItemTemplate>
    </asp:TemplateField>
    <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Like">
    <ItemTemplate>
    <asp:Button ID="Button1" runat="server" Text="Like"  CommandName="Like" CommandArgument='<%# Container.DataItemIndex %>' />
    </ItemTemplate>
    </asp:TemplateField>
    <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="ReTweet">
    <ItemTemplate>
    <asp:Button ID="Button2" runat="server" Text="ReTweet"  CommandName="ReTweet" CommandArgument='<%# Container.DataItemIndex %>' />
    </ItemTemplate>
    </asp:TemplateField>

    <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="TweetID" Visible="true">
    <ItemTemplate>

    <asp:Label ID="lbl_TweetID" runat="server" Text='<%#Eval("TweetID") %>' ></asp:Label>
    </ItemTemplate>
    </asp:TemplateField>
    <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="UserID" Visible="true">
    <ItemTemplate>
    <asp:Label ID="lbl_UserID" runat="server" Text='<%#Eval("UserID") %>' ></asp:Label>
    </ItemTemplate>
    </asp:TemplateField>
    <asp:TemplateField  >  
                    <ItemTemplate >  
                        <asp:LinkButton ID="Edit" runat="server" Text="Edit" CommandName="Edit"  />
                    </ItemTemplate>  
    <EditItemTemplate>  
                        <asp:LinkButton ID="Delete" runat="server" Text="Delete" CommandName="Delete" />
                        <asp:LinkButton ID="btn_Update" runat="server" Text="Update" CommandName="Update"/>
                        <asp:LinkButton ID="btn_Cancel" runat="server" Text="Cancel" CommandName="Cancel"/>  
                    </EditItemTemplate>  
                    </asp:TemplateField>
    </Columns>
    </asp:GridView>
```

.cs:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.UI;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls;
using System.Data;
public partial class Tweets : System.Web.UI.Page
{
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        bool f = true;
        if (!IsPostBack)
        {
            foreach (GridViewRow row in GridView1.Rows)
            {
             Label l = row.FindControl("UserID") as Label;
            //Response.End();
            //if (int.Parse(l.Text.ToString()) != 1)
            //{
            //    Response.End();
            //    row.Cells[7].Visible = false;
            //}
        }
        BindGridview();
        //foreach (GridViewRow row in GridView1.Rows)
        //{
        //    Label l = row.FindControl("UserID") as Label;
        //    Response.Write(l.Text);
        //    //if (int.Parse(l.Text.ToString()) != 1)
        //    //{
        //    //    Response.End();
        //    //    row.Cells[7].Visible = false;
        //    //}
        //}
    }
}
protected void GridView1_RowCommand(object sender, GridViewCommandEventArgs e)
{
    int userId = 1;
    if (e.CommandName == "Like")
    {
        int index = Convert.ToInt32(e.CommandArgument);
        Label l = GridView1.Rows[index].FindControl("lbl_TweetID") as Label;
        TweetHelper.Like(int.Parse(l.Text), userId);
    }
    if (e.CommandName == "ReTweet")
    {
        int index = Convert.ToInt32(e.CommandArgument);
        Label l = GridView1.Rows[index].FindControl("lbl_TweetID") as Label;
        TweetHelper.ReTweet(int.Parse(l.Text), userId);

    }
}
protected void GridView1_RowEditing(object sender, GridViewEditEventArgs e)
{
    GridView1.EditIndex = e.NewEditIndex;

}
protected void GridView1_Cancel(object sender, GridViewCancelEditEventArgs e)
{
    GridView1.EditIndex = -1;
    BindGridview();
}
public void BindGridview()
{
    int userId = 1;
    ServiceReference1.WebServiceSoapClient objWs = new ServiceReference1.WebServiceSoapClient();
    DataSet ds = objWs.SelectTweets(userId, false);
    DataTable dt = ds.Tables[0];
    GridView1.DataSource = dt;
    foreach (GridViewRow row in GridView1.Rows)
    {
        Label l = row.FindControl("UserID") as Label;
        //if (int.Parse(l.Text.ToString()) != 1)
        //{
        //    Response.End();
        //    // row.Cells[7].Visible = false;
        //}
        Response.Write(l.Text);
    }

    //int i = 0,x=0,y=0;
    //DataTable dt1 = new DataTable();
    //foreach (DataRow row in dt.Rows)
    //{
    //    foreach (object obj in row.ItemArray)
    //    {
    //        dt1.Rows.Add(dt.Rows[x][4]);
    //        x++;
    //    }

    //}
    //foreach (DataRow row in dt1.Rows)
    //{
    //    foreach (object obj in row.ItemArray)
    //    {
    //        if (obj.ToString() == userId.ToString())
    //        {
    //            GridView1.Rows[i].FindControl("Buttons").Visible = true;
    //        }
    //        else
    //        {
    //            GridView1.Rows[i].FindControl("Buttons").Visible = false;
    //        }
    //        i++;
    //    }
    //}
    GridView1.DataBind();
    foreach (GridViewRow row in GridView1.Rows)
    {
        Label l = row.FindControl("UserID") as Label;
        //if (int.Parse(l.Text.ToString()) != 1)
        //{
        //    Response.End();
        //    // row.Cells[7].Visible = false;
        //}
        Response.Write(l.Text);
    }

}
protected void GridView1_RowUpdating(object sender, GridViewUpdateEventArgs e)
{
    Label TweetID = GridView1.Rows[e.RowIndex].FindControl("lbl_TweetID") as Label;
    TextBox TweetText = GridView1.Rows[e.RowIndex].FindControl("Tbx_Tweet") as TextBox;
    TweetHelper.Updatetweet(int.Parse(TweetID.Text), TweetText.Text);
    GridView1.EditIndex = -1;
    BindGridview();
}
protected void GridView1_RowDeleting(object sender, GridViewDeleteEventArgs e)
{

}
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have more options to do it.

1. Create RowDataBound event handler and set up edit button Visibile/Enable property:

   ```
   protected void GridView1_RowDataBound(object sender, GridViewRowEventArgs e)
   {   
       if (e.Row.RowType == DataControlRowType.DataRow)
       {
           Label userIdLbl = (Label)e.Row.FindControl("lbl_UserID");
           LinkButton editBt = (LinkButton)e.Row.FindControl("Edit");
           editBt.Visible = currentUserId == Convert.ToInt32(userIdLbl.Text);
       }
   }
   ```
2. Create a method in your code behind to check if the userId is currentUserId and add the attribute Visible/Enable to your edit button in gridview template:

   ```
   Visible='<%# IsCurentUserId((int)Eval("UserID")) %>
   ```